# Erro em função mail() - Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: php, phpmailer

Bom, pesquisei a respeito do erro, muitos usuários disseram que deve ser adicionado o `ssl://` ao `smtp.google.com` ou o `tls://` ao `imap.google.com`, usando as portas  465(ou 993 como alternativa) e 587 respectivamente.
Testei diversas configurações de usuários do próprio stackoverflow, nenhuma conseguiu dar um fim à esse problema.

php.ini

```
[mail function]
SMTP=imap.gmail.com
smtp_port=587

sendmail_from = xxxxxxx@gmail.com

mail.add_x_header=On
```

sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=imap.gmail.com

smtp_port=587

smtp_ssl=auto

error_logfile=error.log

auth_username=xxxxxx@gmail.com
auth_password=xxxxxxx
```

script de envio

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$assunto = $_POST["assunto"];
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];
$mensagem = wordwrap($mensagem, 70);
$mensagem = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $mensagem);
$email = $_POST["email"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
#Montagem do e-mail
$from = $email;
$to = "gamboamurilo@gmail.com";
$subject = $assunto;
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: {$from}" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "To: {$to}" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: " . phpversion();
$message = "<p>{$nome}</p><br />
            <p>{$email}</p><br />
            <p>{$telefone}</p><br />
            <br />
            <p>{$assunto}</p><br />
            <p>{$mensagem}</p>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Aviso retornado:

```
mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b62-v6sm6183858qkj.48 - gsmtp in C:\xampp\htdocs\willy\contact_form.php on line 25
```

Como posso corrigir o problema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto esta bem errado:

```
imap.gmail.com
```

Imap é para receber e não para enviar emails, são protocolos totalmente distintos, provavelmente o correto seja:

```
SMTP="ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
smtp_port=465
```

Como citado nesta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265792/1518921 ou:

```
SMTP="tsl://smtp.gmail.com";
smtp_port=587
```

Se o SSL não funcionar (não sei como anda o Gmail)

Note que no `php.ini` não podem conter espaços nos valores:

```
sendmail_from = xxxxxxx@gmail.com
```

O correto seria:

```
sendmail_from=xxxxxxx@gmail.com
```

Só que é importante ter em mente que você precisa ter o SSL ativo no php, via `php.ini`, então tire o ; de frente do ;extension

Se for windows (php até a versão 7.1):

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Se for linux ou mac (php até a versão 7.1):

```
;extension=openssl.so
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
extension=openssl.so
```

Se for PHP7.2 independente de windows, linux ou mac deve ser assim:

```
;extension=openssl
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
extension=openssl
```

Depois de editar o php.ini é necessário reiniciar o teu servidor HTTP, geralmente é o apache.

Comment: isso mesmo, ele deu erro com os dois, mas aparentemente é bloqueio no próprio servidor do gmail

Comment: @Murilo Certeza que é exatamente a mesma mensagem né? Bem, vou confiar :) ... faz um teste, retira os espaços de `sendmail_from = xxxxxxx@gmail.com`, assim `sendmail_from=xxxxxxx@gmail.com`.

Comment: rodou sem espaços

Comment: @MuriloGambôa editei a resposta e adicionei isto, vou apagar todos meus comentários, se precisar de algo mais me avise